# When I Attempt To Keep My Layout Grounded It Goes Out Of Control In The Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the newest version of android studio. So, I've been trying to anchor my listview so it stops moving to the top left, but no matter what I try, it won't anchor down. The text "Hi, how are you?" is the note in the textview.

[My Image Of Layout And Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCUuH.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jackson.collegeplanner.Schedule">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="439dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: would help if u loaded your layout xml

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded it. I never code XML, so I never use it. Its uploaded.

Comment: Have you tried increasing layout_marginStart and layout_marginTop? What else have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to use `match_parent` for the width of your EditText and for both the width and height of your ListView. `ConstraintLayout` **does not support** `match_parent`.

Android Studio is weird about this. Sometimes things appear to work just fine. Sometimes it starts replacing your `match_parent` values with fixed dimension sizes and adds `tools:` attributes to position your views.

Anyway, change these:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="322dp"
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="439dp"
```

to these instead:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Using `0dp` for width/height inside `ConstraintLayout` means "make me large enough to satisfy my constraints". So the EditText will stretch from the start of the parent to the start of the Button, and the ListView will stretch from the start of the parent to the end of the parent as well as stretch from the bottom of the EditText to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: Actually the posted layout (in the question) loads alright on my emulator. The edit text and listview position correctly on the screen. Wondering how/why it starts off the screen (like the attached image in question)?

Comment: If those dimensions are hardcoded intentionally, that's _still_ the reason the layout displays incorrectly on your phone. Different devices have different screen sizes; a width of `368dp` probably works great for your 410dp-wide emulator but much worse on a 360dp-wide phone. I highly recommend you switch the hardcoded dimensions to `0dp` as in my answer so that the views can grow/shrink to fit the actual screen size.

Comment: Yup. makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.